# JFrame and JPanel size not changing in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i'm making a car game and i just got a problem with the size of the screen, it isnt allowing the car to move(it should be able to move on all the screen), maybe the size of the jpanel isnt the right size.

Main and JPanel :

```
public class MyCarGame extends JPanel implements Runnable {

CarPlayer Player;

public MyCarGame(GUI frame) {
    Player = new CarPlayer(0, 0);

    this.setSize(WidthFrame,HeightFrame);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener());

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    Player.draw(g);
    repaint();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    draw(g);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Player.move();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyCarGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            Player.xVel = 3;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            Player.xVel = -3;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            Player.yVel = -3;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            Player.yVel = 3;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            Player.xVel = 0;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            Player.yVel = -1;
            break;

    }
}
}

public static int WidthFrame = 0;
public static int HeightFrame = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    new GUI().setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Player class :

```
public class CarPlayer {
int x;
int y;
Image img;
public  int xVel;
public int yVel;
public CarPlayer(int x,int y){

img= new ImageIcon("images/PlayerCar.png").getImage();  
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
xVel=0;
yVel=-1;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}


public void move(){
    if(x+xVel<(MyCarGame.WidthFrame-50) && x+xVel>0)
x+=xVel;
    if(y+yVel<(MyCarGame.HeightFrame-100) && y+yVel>0)
y+=yVel;
if(x<0){
xVel=0;
}
if(y<0){
    yVel=0;

}
if(y>(MyCarGame.HeightFrame-100)){ 
yVel=0;
}
if(x>(MyCarGame.WidthFrame-50)){  
    xVel=0;
}
}



public void draw(Graphics g){

g.drawImage(img, x, y,50,100, null);

}

}
```

Frame class:

```
 public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form GUI
 */
 MyCarGame g;
public GUI() {
    this.setFocusable(false);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    MyCarGame.WidthFrame=this.getWidth(); 
    MyCarGame.HeightFrame=this.getHeight(); 
    g=new MyCarGame(this);
    this.add(g);
    g.setLocation(0, 0);
    g.requestFocusInWindow();
    Thread t= new Thread(g);
    t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` for animation.

Comment: `WidthFrame` and `HeightFrame` are `0`?  What do you expect.  Don't use `static` fields for this, pass the information that the `Player` needs to know, ie, the actual size of the component...

Comment: Don't call `repaint` (or any method that might call `repaint`) from within any paint method

Comment: okay i got it, but after i use setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); it doesnt give the maximized values, i did         System.out.println(this.getSize().toString()); and it doesnt show the maximized values i expected

Comment: This is because the frame has not been realised. `setExtendedState` actually relies on the `GraphicsDevice` to make determinations about what it can do

Comment: okay but is there a way to know what is the real value of maximized vertical or horizontal ? because i would like to allow car move on all the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on "magic" values, or attempting to...

```
public GUI() {
    this.setFocusable(false);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    MyCarGame.WidthFrame = this.getWidth();
    MyCarGame.HeightFrame = this.getHeight();
```

At this point, the frames size is still `0x0`, because until you try and make it visible, the frame doesn't really know what screen it will be displayed on.

These values also do not take into account the possible insets that a frame border might have, and they change between platforms and look and feels (and can even change across different instances of the same platform)

Simple solution, get rid of it.  `static` is not a good choice for this, a better solution would be to change your `move` method to require the caller to pass in the width and height of the available space...

For example...

```
public void move(int width, int height) {
```

Then when you need to call it, you could use something like...

```
Player.move(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Avoid `KeyListener`, it's just troublesome, consider using the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.  It provides better control over the level of focus required to trigger the key event...

Don't call `repaint`, directly or indirectly, from within any paint method, this is simply going to continue to raise a paint event, which will eventually consume your CPU

On my system, `setResizable` didn't play nicely with `setExtendedState`...you might want to consider getting rid of the `setResizable` option...

Comment: i got it working now, thank you. but i didnt understand then shouldn't i use repaint() ? i will add some other images moving too and yeah i will pass the width and  height  to method move

Comment: You can use `repaint`, but not within the context of the `paint` method. Swing uses a passive renderer engine, meaning that a paint might be triggered for any number reasons, many you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a little advice, for names of variables, use lower-case letters.

Second, don't ask to repaint on the draw() method on MyCarGame class, if you are already painting. You should ask it instead after you move the car. And your game loop need more control. 
About the game loop, use this link: https://www.google.pt/#q=java+game+loop

Comment: so do you mean i should use repaint on run method ?

Comment: Yes I do mean that.

A simple game loop has: 1st updateGame(), 2nd renderGame() (or repaint()), 3rd sleep().

This link shows that: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0